# Busted OS X Python install

Tags: python, macos, osx-leopard

So I didn't look carefully and I installed 64 bit Python2.7 on an OS X 10.5 box. This didn't work with the standard cryptic wrong-OS message "dyld: unknown required load command"

OK, fair enough

So I dragged the Python2.7 icon to the trash from Applications; then I went in with sudo and renamed the

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/

to

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7BROKEN/

and installed the 32-bit Python 2.7. But I am still getting the "dyld" error. Any idea what other side effect the broken install might have had to make this possible and how I can fix it?

Comment: Which distribution of Python are using? Did you look for instructions from that distro about how to uninstall? Why did you remove from trash and rename etc. instead of uninstalling and starting over?

Comment: Sounds like a pickle.  Not a solution for the current situation but maybe try to install python using `brew install python` (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) next time.  That will install it in /usr/local/bin and not mess with the OS version.

Comment: Jim, the complete uninstall story is rather ugly:

http://bugs.python.org/issue7107 

Why I renamed rather than deleting? Superstition perhaps. I don't like deleting files before I have a problem solved. I didn;t remove anything from trash.

Comment: Point taken about ugly uninstall story. My mistake about dragging from the trash. I'm typing on a small screen and can't see what I'm replying to.

Comment: Problem solved by following http://bugs.python.org/issue7107 instructions, substituting 2.7 for 2.6 everywhere, then reinstalling.

Comment: You should answer your own question, and accept it, for completeness :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by following this [bug report's](http://bugs.python.org/issue7107) instructions, substituting 2.7 for 2.6 everywhere, then reinstalling.